# Single-select Win32 ListView (Common Controls)

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, common-controls

I'm using the ListView control from Common Controls 6.0 in C++ and I need the ListView to be single-select only.

All of the higher level controls have this feature (e.g. .Net and Qt), but I imagine they are based on this control deep down somewhere. Any ideas on how I can get this to behave as a single-select list?

Just in case it makes a difference, here is my current create statement:

```
list = ::CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    WC_LISTVIEWW,
    NULL,
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDATA,
    0,
    0,
    250,
    400,
    parentWindow,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the flag `LVS_SINGLESEL`

This flag must be used in window creation, changing it after creation will fail - can't toggle between single and multi select without creating 2 separate controls.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information on not being able to toggle it, that will actually come in very handy!

Answer (score 3):

There's a LVS_SINGLESEL style. Just OR that in with the styles you already have.

Answer (score 2):

You want `LVS_SINGLESEL`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774739.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation, I swear I looked through that list five different times... Maybe it was the extended styles I was looking through, actually...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want add any code, just edit the Dialog RC property.
[image]